# Detect adding control to form

Tags: c#

Hi
I write a component and need to when one control add to form i detect this event and add this control to my component list , is this possible ? (Design time)

excuse me for my poor english
tnx

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controladded.aspx) event?

**EDIT:**
The event is raised in DesignTime either.

I created `Form2` class:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {
    public Form2() {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.ControlAdded += new ControlEventHandler(Form2_ControlAdded);
    }

    void Form2_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {
        this.Text += " " + e.Control.Name;
    }
}
```

And then I created `Form3` class derived from `Form2` class.

```
public partial class Form3 : Form2 {
    public Form3() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

After that I recompiled solution, opened designer of `Form3` class, added new `Button` from ToolBox and the `Text` property of form was changed from "Form3" to "Form3 button1".

Comment: No , this event occur when control added to form in runtime , but i want to be in "Design Time"

Comment: actually i want to have a list of my component parent form controls and i want to update this list by hooking (Detecting) adding control to form.

Comment: Look at my "edit" part. Are you sure, you attach "ControlAdded" event on correct control (form)? Do you know, the "ControlAdded" event does not work hierarchically?

Comment: I would like help you, but If I don't have code of your component and don't know what the component should do, I can not help :(.